# "Audio port not available" on DVD-ROM drive

Tags: dvd, optical-drive, compact-disc

I'm currently rebuilding a vintage PC (DOS 6.22 **only**) and I need to replace the IDE CD-ROM.

The one I bought (IDE DVD burner) have the SPDIF (2 pin) and 4 pin audio ports but the drive is labeled "audio port not available". I usually don't care since I can't count the number of years I haven't used these (AFAIK since Windows XP those are useless), but since my PC is a relic, I need them (at least the SPDIF one).

Anyone knows a DVD model (burner or not - still available online) that have working audio ports (I **need** the SPDIF - 2 pin one)?

PS: The one I bought wasen't advertised as with or without audio ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with an IDE ASUS DVD-E818A4 which have functionnal SPDIF (2 pin) and 4 pin audio ports.